# Matching gfortran with gcc compiler

Tags: 14.04, gcc, r

I'm running gcc (Ubuntu 5.3.0-3ubuntu1~14.04) 5.3.0 20151204

I can't successfully install some R packages because I'm getting an error with my gfortran.  Someone indicated it might be because my g++ isn't matching my gfortran version.

This is my gfortran: GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 4.8.5-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 4.8.5

Can someone help me get these to work together so I can install R packages like lavaan and it's dependencies.  Thank you.

Comment: Can you show us the errors you get while installing the problematic R packages? How do you know that someone's advice is right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several versions of the gcc,g++, gfortran compilers are availble.  For instance, packages g++-5, gcc-5 and gfortran-5, vs the ...-4 versions.  You apparently don't have the gfortran-5 padkage.  There are meta packages for the compilers, gcc, g++, and gfortran to get the dependencies for the latest versions.  Probably one of those was not installed so it's package (gfortran?).  Anyway, just:

```
sudo apt-get install gfortran
```

to see if you get the expected 5.3 version to match your gcc.
If that doesn't work, just use the explicit gfortran-5 package.

Comment: Thanks! sudo apt-get install gfortran-5  did it!!  semPlot, corrplot, lavaan etc all installed.  For semPlot, I did have to run sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev  in terminal and install.packages("XML") to get the dependencies working, but all is well!